# Keen IO Chart Labels

Tags: keen-io

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the labels on an Area Chart visualization of my Keen IO data.  I've looked through the available configuration options, but I'm not seeing what option would do this.  Currently my chart just lists "null" on the legend on the right side of the chart, and on the hover tooltips when you hover over a particular peak.  Just looking to switch it to list "Hits" instead of "null."

Does anyone know how/where I would configure those labels?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `labelMapping`for that. Something like:

```
client.draw(funnel, document.getElementById("chart"), { 
    library: "google",
    chartType: "columnchart",
    labelMapping: {
        null: "Hits"
    }
});
```